# How do I bring out the garlic flavor in an oil base?

Tags: flavor, spices, garlic

I make a lot of Indian food, so the preparation begins with a base made of onions, ginger, and garlic. I start by frying the onions in oil and then adding ginger and garlic as the onions begin to brown. Then I cook both until the onions are thoroughly browned and the citrus smell of the ginger fades.

I can't taste the garlic in my food though. I am careful not to burn the garlic... is there anything else I should look out for?

Comment: What kind of garlic are you using? Commercial ground garlic paste/powder/whole clove?

Answer (score 1):

Sauté the garlic separately and allow it to rest in its cooking oil until the other herbs are completely cooked. After you have added the other ingredients of the recipe, add the garlic for the last stage of the cooking. The earlier you add the garlic, the more it will get cooked into the other flavors and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Pre sautéed the garlic or add whole cloves to the cooking oil, crush down the cloves to release flavor and then remove. Proceed as usual. P.S. NEVER store garlic submerged in oil. It can produce botulism toxin introduced from the growing soil. Botulism bacteria are anaerobic meaning they survive without air as is the case when covered in oil.

Answer (score 1):

Even I love Indian recipes to the core and prepare it on a daily basis. Coming to your question, I am sure garlic flavor is infused well with your curry, but that you are unable to highlight it. That should be it. If you really want garlicky flavor more, simply try adding it more than usual. Nevertheless I am pretty sure the amount of garlic usually used does its job. You can experiment it by making a curry with only ginger, and the same curry with garlic added. The latter though you can't taste garlic highlightedly , you can find much difference between both of the curries. Also try reducing ginger a little bit. Ginger is so strongly flavored and adding a little bit is enough. So try adding more garlic and reduce the Ginger quantity. I understand your concern as I am myself a garlic lover. Try the tricks mentioned and see if those work. Happy cooking!